# How do I force objects to follow another object?

Tags: game-engine, modifiers, objects, snapping

I'm trying to add a ring of diamonds to a character's wristwatch in a game, and it all works well until I get to testing it in-game, where the diamonds don't really follow the path of the watch at all. I've tried various forms of placement and functions I thought would solve my problem, but nothing has worked so far. Is there a specific blender function that let's me pin and object to another object so that it moves in tandem with it?

Comment: Please post some screenshots.

Comment: Do you use an armature at your character? Is the watch a separate object, or a skin object on the armature (it has an armature modifier)? Is the watch bone-parented to an arm bone? How did you connect the watch and the ring? Why do you need such tiny object (the ring) to be separate?

Comment: The character is already in the game, and I'm trying to apply a mod to it. I'm limited by the game's structure, which makes this particularly difficult. I don't have access to armature and the watch is parented to the character's arm bone, but I can't edit the character itself, only the watch. This is why I want the ring of diamonds to follow the watch (because I can't get it to follow the character's arm itself, so I figured making it follow the watch would be easier).

Comment: Tried "make vertex parent" yet?

Comment: The watch is parented to the bone. The ring is parented to the watch. It should work. But this sometimes does not work if one or more parents have an in-homogene scaling (not all axes have the same scale). I wonder why you do not have access to the character. Is it an instance of a group?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmmmm. Can't manipulate the model at. Try making a base mesh that fits the models shape, parent THAT to the model, add the watch and ring to that base mesh.  Delete the mesh but keep the accessories. This should. .."SHOULD" fix the axis problem as if the base is positioned properly, the watch and ring should inherit is rotation, scale and all that jazz from the mesh when you delete it but keep the watch and ring "IN" the initial mesh object.